# How to specify type of UseState output in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got a variable whose initial value I want to be `null`, but I want to be able to set it as a `number` as well.

`const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);`

When I write `setIntervalId(2);` in my code later, it complains that argument type number is not assignable to `SetActionState<null>`.

What's the proper way to define such a variable in React?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple:

```
const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState<null | number>(null);
```

Comment: I figured this out literally moments after i asked the question, thank you very much. I'll mark as correct when the timer lets me.